# How to authenticate on an ASP.NET 4.0 application and Redirect to ASP.NET 3.5 app

Tags: asp.net

On a Windows Server 2003 machine running IIS 6 I have an ASP.NET 4.0 web application on its own website (**http://authorize.com**) that has the Login.aspx page.  When the login button is pressed it authenticates the user with:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("spud", False)        
Response.Redirect("http://legacy.com/Default.aspx")
```

In the web.config of **authorize.com** I have the authentication configured like so:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx"
             timeout="5000000"
             ticketCompatibilityMode="Framework20"
             protection="Validation">
</authentication>
<authorization>
   <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
<machineKey decryptionKey="AF96F355CEC57EFD2F996515BF465166075E596F19EB9B47"
   validationKey="5C9D7A8F3E336278F771C7FE45B65BF6E9B41BA9575F04672CCC4242B225DD399FAF7B806B2CD5545200CD0E63A8991CA6BFB2D77FE9C5B0D69889359574C5F3" 
   validation="SHA1" 
   decryption="3DES"/>
```

I also have an ASP.NET 3.5 web application on a different website (**http://legacy.com**).
It has a web.config of:

What is currently happening is when you go to **http://legacy.com/Default.aspx** it redirects you to **http://authorize.com/Login.aspx** and then when you click the login button it takes you back to the Login.aspx page as if you were not authenticated.

How do I configure my sites so that the ASP.NET 3.5 site can share the authentication token of the ASP.NET 4.0 site?

**EDIT**: I had to explicitly add protection="Validation" in the forms tag of all web.config's to make the ASPXAUTH cookie the same length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browser does not pass cookies of one domain to another domain - so in your case, cookies for `authroize.com` and `legacy.com` have different scopes and browser will not share them. So your scheme will not work.

However, if you can make both sites as a part of same domain (e.g. `authroize.myite.com` and `legacy.mysite.com`) then cookie created as parent domain (`mysite.com`) will be shared across both sites. Note that ASP.NET allows you to set the domain for the cookie [using domain attribute of forms configuration element](http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/forms-authentication-configuration-and-advanced-topics-vb). Of course, you still need to have same set of machine keys for both the servers.

For cross-domain authentication to work, you have to basically implement single sign-on feature. In your case, a implementation outline will be would be

1. Legacy site will redirect to authentication site for authentication passing the return url
2. authentication site will authenticate the user, set the cookie for itself and then redirect to legacy site return url passing the token for the authenticated user.
3. A simplistic implementation for a token can be user identity encrypted by shared private key. However to avoid replay attacks etc, you need to add time-stamp into the token. Also legacy site also needs to pass some random salt value while requesting authentication that will be used for hashing etc.
4. Once legacy site receives the user token, it validates the token (by decrypting it, checking hash & time-stamp etc) and set its own authentication cookie.

See [this link (for subdomain)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/SingleSignon.aspx) & [this link (for cross domain)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CrossDomainSSOModel.aspx) that describes above approaches in more detail.